# Why did older languages lose the informal "you" if modern languages are losing the formal "you"?

Tags: historical-linguistics, language-change, sociolinguistics, formality

English and (I believe) Brazilian Portuguese have to varying degrees lost T-V distinction via adoption of the formal second-person pronoun for both formal and informal situations. English completely lost "thou" and "thee", and Brazilian Portuguese largely lost "tu". I ask because modern languages seem to be gradually expanding use of the *informal* second-person pronoun to cover more situations traditionally using the formal, losing T-V distinction in the opposite way.

It's easy to imagine a cultural decrease in formality leading to a protracted loss of the formal pronoun, but it's fairly difficult to imagine the forces that would lead to a loss of the informal. Was there a period of increasing formality that saw loss of the informal pronoun in English and Brazilian Portuguese?

Comment: Also Spanish *vos* and *Ustedes*

Comment: Why is it difficult to imagine forces leading to the loss of the informal pronouns? Increased formality is one way to word it; another is to suppose that informal pronouns gradually became more and more _familiar_ (used with family and close friends, but with everyone else it’s safer to use the formal ones lest anyone take offence), eventually becoming _derogatory_ (oi, you there!) and being ousted completely. That’s roughly the opposite of what’s currently happening in many societies, where the formal is becoming distant and cold, so the informal is safer, but both are perfectly likely.

Comment: Thou and thee were 2nd person singular in English.  We now extend the use of the 2nd person plural in English to the 2nd person singular.

Comment: @PerryWebb the loss of the 2nd person singular in English seems to have occurred after English (at least fashionable London English) adopted a T-V distinction (possibly under French influence), so at the time of its loss (in the de facto contemporary standard) it was a loss of the informal singular

Comment: Formal pronouns appeared in European paradigms [around the 18th and 19th century](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/151925/15299). There was always flattery of nobles, but with more nobles one needed paradigmatic flattery.

Comment: **What you say about Portuguese is simply not true**. Iberian Portuguese very much uses **tu** as do the African varieties and it is common in northern and southern Brazil. You really should explain what you mean more clearly. I find it confusing. In Portugal, you say tu to your friends, but O senhor or A senhora and você  to accompany these latter.

Comment: @Lambie Did you bother to actually read the question? It specifically talks about Brazilian Portuguese, and says that it **largely** lost _tu_, which is completely correct by number of speakers. Iberian and African varieties of Portuguese are completely irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Sorry, but what is **actually lost** is the **second person plural vos**. I happen to be a native Brazilian Portuguese speaker for most intents and purposes. The tu pronoun is not "largely lost" at all. https://br.ifunny.co/picture/o-uso-do-pronome-tu-e-voce-no-portugues-brasileiro-iUpT27kp8 And this: "adoption of the formal second-person pronoun for both formal and informal situations" is completely inaccurate. No one anywhere in the Lusophone world uses the second person plural today except in some archaic literary way or hyper-formal context.

Comment: @Lambie Incorrect. _Vós_ is still used dialectally in northern Portugal, which is very much within the Lusophone world. And at the time when it was lost throughout most of Portuguese, it was not the default formal second-person pronoun; the battle was not between _tu_ and _vós_, but between _tu_ and _você_. You can argue whether _você_ is second or third person as a pronoun, but it functions at least pragmatically as second-person.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Look, the OP is wrong about Brazil. And the fringe use of the second person plural in northern Portuguese is not relevant. And no, you can't argue about whether você is a second or third person. There is no doubt. It is third person singular pronoun. That's important because of how **verbs are conjugated**. Why are you fighting with me about a language you don't even speak? I don't get it.

Comment: @Lambie So by your logic, _tu_ is presumably also a third person pronoun in the south of Brazil where it’s commonly used with third-person agreement? There are different ways to define what person a pronoun belongs to. Which verbal form it takes for agreement purposes is one, formal; which real-world referent it is used to refer to is another, pragmatic. The two do not always coincide.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The tu is not third person. In any place where it is used regardless of endings. And now we are back to square one. The tu is used in many places in Brazil. Period. The OP is mistaken. No use continuing this discussion.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few situations where the "T" pronoun in a T-V distinction (e.g. thou/you, ty/vy, tú/usted...) might become socially proscribed and avoided:

1. if its usage implies that the hearer is below the speaker in the social hierarchy, in a society where drawing attention upon this would be considered belittling.
2. if higher class speakers already use the "V" pronoun among themselves, even when there's no hierarchy between them. As such, the usage of the "T" pronoun becomes associated with the lower classes, and stigmatised.
3. if the "T" pronoun implies more familiarity than people are generally comfortable with, making its usage feel invasive towards someone's personal space.

English likely lost "thou" due to a mix of those three factors.

Regarding Portuguese, it's worth to note that even in Brazil plenty speakers use "tu", depending on their actual dialects; for example the pronoun is practically non-existent in Paulistano dialect, but commonplace in Gaúcho. In the dialects that lost it, the process was likely similar as in English (i.e. "tu" was seen as too familiar, belittling, and something that stigmatised groups would use). The language eventually redeveloped the distinction with "o senhor" (roughly "sir") as the new respectful pronoun, and in a few dialects (as in e.g. Santa Catarina) you see a three-way distinction between:

- tu - familiar, non-hierarchical
- você - distant, non-hierarchical
- o senhor - hierarchical

Because of that, even with how common "você" has become, it's possible that "tu" will still survive for longer, as there is no pressure to remove it for sounding belittling or "low class" any more.

Answer (score 1):

The most interesting theory I've heard (with regard to English) is that it was caused by an increasing tendency for people to leave their rural homes and move to a city. It became ordinary for people to use the formal almost all the time because it was the appropriate choice in the context. It became a habit.

So it's highly likely that, in a manner of speaking, there was a period of increasing formality in the culture that caused the informal form to wither.